Помогите, пожалуйста, говорит, что нет столбца 'geg', хотя он есть
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *

sql = sqlite3.connect('DB.db')
curs = sql.cursor()

curs.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS any_guitar (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name_of_guitar TEXT NOT NULL,
    form TEXT NOT NULL,
    pickups TEXT NOT NULL,
    price INTEGER NOT NULL
)
''')
sql.close()

def send_to_table():
    sql = sqlite3.connect('DB.db')
    curs = sql.cursor()
    geg = name_entry.get()
    feg = form_entry.get()
    peg = pickup_entry.get()
    preg = price_entry.get()
    curs.execute('''
    INSERT INTO any_guitar (name_of_guitar, form, pickups, price) VALUES (geg, feg, peg, preg)
    ''')
    sql.commit()
    sql.close()

wind = Tk()
wind.title('Добавление гитары в список')

label = Label(wind, text="Впишите в поля")
label.pack()

label_name = Label(wind, text="Фирма, Серия, Модель гитары")
label_name.pack()

name_entry = Entry()
name_entry.pack()

label_name = Label(wind, text="Форма гитары")
label_name.pack()

form_entry = Entry()
form_entry.pack()

label_name = Label(wind, text="Звукосниматели на гитаре")
label_name.pack()

pickup_entry = Entry()
pickup_entry.pack()

label_name = Label(wind, text="Цена гитары")
label_name.pack()

price_entry = Entry()
price_entry.pack()

send_to_table_button = Button(wind, text="Отправить в таблицу", command=send_to_table)
send_to_table_button.pack()

wind.mainloop()

